# I deleted my firebase project thinking that it would remove the hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I deleted my firebase project because i thought that it would cancel out the hostinf too now im getting this error altough i changed the host.[image]

what can do?

Comment: The question isn't clear. Are you saying you have deleted the project from Firebase but still shows up? Have you removed the DNS records that were required to verify your domain?

Comment: i just deleted the firebase project please help what can i do

Comment: What do you mean by you changed the host? Have you updated your DNS record? Check if they are updated [here](https://dnschecker.org/). Try using other browser, that must be cached.

Comment: i tried with A all of it resolved i deleted the cache and tried on opera browser but its still showing

Comment: if u created for simple project u can create new one, but if u used for great project it is great mistake, contact with firebase I recommend u

Comment: i restored the project from my email how can i shut the hosting down

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I had to change the dns from the place where i bought the domain.